# How can I fix the error "tau_file_system is not defined" in tau-prolog?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tau-prolog

I wanted to execute swi prolog code in a react/typescript component, where I got the error "tau_file_system is not defined". My code looks like this (the code is from the tau-prolog github page):

```
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import pl from "tau-prolog";

function PrologTest() {
 const onClick = () =\> {
  const session = pl.create();
  session.consult(
  "likes(sam, salad).
   likes(dean, pie).
   likes(sam, apples).
   likes(dean, whiskey).",

   {
    success: function () {
    console.log("YES");
   },
    error: function (err: any) {
     console.log("NO");
    },
   }
  );
  session.query("likes(sam, X).", {
   success: function (goal: any) {
    console.log("YES");
   },
   error: function (err: any) {
    console.log("NO");
   },
  });
 };

return (
  <div className="container"\>
   <Button onClick={onClick}\>XSD TO JSOn\</Button\>
  </div\>
);
}

export default PrologTest;
```

I looked at the documentation and the issues of the project, but could not find where my problem could be (I am still a beginner with js/ts, nodejs etc).

Do any of you have any idea how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Hi. I've hit the same issue. Did you find any solution?